# I want to change an Excel Column with user's input

Tags: excel, pandas, input

I receive reports from a database and I'm trying to change the dates on a column based on the user's input.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('eFile.xls')
print = ('Please enter the End of Week Date: ')
eDate = input()
```

So I want to change a row called 'EndDate' based on my user's input. The column is a datetime64 filetype and already has a date. Do I need to change it to a string before I can change it and how do I change every cell? I need to change over 3000 cells with this input.

Answer (score 0):

First convert the user input to a pandas datetime format:

```
new_date = pd.to_datetime(eDate)
```

Then, insert it into your dataframe:

```
df.loc[0, 'EndDate'] = new_date
```

where 0 is the row index.

To set the new date for the entire column:

```
df['EndDate'] = new_date
```

Comment: How can I change it for the entire column and not just one row?